Сравнение даты и времени timestamp dataframe
Необходимо сравнить дату и время двух различных DataFram`ов
for i in range(0, len(symbol_list)):
    if df.iloc[-1:]['time'] != check_bar.loc[i, 'time']:
        print(check_bar.loc[i,'symbol'], 'новый бар!')
        check_bar.loc[i, 'time'] = df.iloc[-1:]['time']

В этом случае логично возникает ошибка. Функции squeeze() и values() тут не применимы. Есть вариант сконвертировать в строку. Какой еще вариант возможен?

вы бы пример датафреймов привели в вопросе в воспроизводимом виде. вообще, вопрос сделайте боле развернутым: возможно, вам подскажут более эффективное решение, чем перебор фрейма в цикле.
